# How to use a file viewer with vuejs2

Tags: pdf, vuejs2, vue-component, viewer

I created a vuejs 2 application with the vue-cli  and I want to read a .pdf file with a "pdf viewwer" as viewerjs.
I tried with the npm viewerjs library but I did not know how to use it in a .vue component.

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Can you add some code, create a fiddle?

Comment: I downloaded the npm librarie viewerjs and followed the instructions but i don't have any idea how to make it work properly...
[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruwhr5b0/)